# T-SQL : extracting a subset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question in a question book but I'm stuck:

Q: Table `DebtPayment_DL` in database `PaymentLoad` needs a subset of information extracting to display `DebtAccountReferences` which have a `PaymentStartDate` after `01/01/2021` and no close date.

The schema:

```
    [DebtAccountReferences] - varchar(50) not null
    [PaymentStartDate] - datetime, not null
    [CloseDate] - Datetime, not null
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DebtPayment_DL 
WHERE PaymentStartDate > 01/01/2021 AND CloseDate IS NULL
```

Now do I need a join statement as well to join the table `DebtPayment_DL` with `DebtAccountReferences`? Also if this is wrong please correct me.

I'm not exactly sure what the result is, I don't think there's a specific result just a vivid idea.

Comment: Please share table structure of statement table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be any joining since the information is available in that table. Instead of selecting all the columns you can select only DebtAccountReferences as required.

```
select DebtAccountReferences
from DebtPayment_DL 
where PaymentStartDate > '01/01/2021' and CloseDate is null;
```

Comment: Umm, are you sure sql server will parse `01/01/2021` as a date!? I'd strongly recommend using `'2021-01-01'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have given, you do not need a join statement. All of the information you need is stored in the table 'DebtPayment_DL'

Your code is therefore correct and should generate the correct output.